# Error in Ruby Mine - Synthax Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

ruby mine pop out a error for this line of code:

```
scope :to_activate, -> {where("start_date < ? AND active = 0", DateTime.now)}
```

error is on the ->

Message is:

```
Exception: expression
```

whats wrong in this line?

Comment: What ruby version are you using?

Comment: Using SublimeLinter::Ruby, no problem with this line of code.

Comment: @ArslanAli im running on ruby 2.1

Comment: the key to helping anyone debug your problem is by providing as much context as possible. usually, that leads to debug the problem yourself. this post might help you with that http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: sorry but there is no more content ... page works but in rubymin there is an error